# Xamarin Form auto exit after install nuget package

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I faced some weird problem in VS2017 Xamarin Form. I created a Cross-Platform App (Xamarin Form) with .Net Standard. I got no problem when running the new blank app. But after I install the Microsoft Azure Devices Client from nuget package manager, it shows the error `Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json`. I installed the Newtonsoft.Json and every package that cant be found including Microsoft Azure Devices Shared, Microsoft Windows Azure Storage, Dotnetty Transport, Dotnetty codecs mqtt, and Dotnetty handlers. Then the app ran but exit before showing anything. The log is too long so I put it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u153wvqTfQRFnCheKr6ETq2YAWEg3xWc).

Comment: Could the path length of some of the files exceed 240 characters?

Comment: Could `D:\VS2017\App2` exceed 240 characters?